# Connect to Firestore Emulator locally and production at the same time

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have the need to connect to my production database in my Firebase Emulator project.

In my case it's to access renewed tokens that I have stored in the production database.

I've tried launching a second instance as stated in the Firestore documentation, and i get the console message:

> Non-default "firebase-admin" instance created! - This instance will *not* be mocked and will access production resources.

However it still connects to my local database.

I've also set:

```
const settings = { host: 'xxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com'
}
let db = admin.firestore()
db.settings(settings)
```

But when inspected, the instance is still set to localhost.

I'm thinking it might have to do with something with process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR that overrides the settings?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: As it is using the Firestore Emulator, you may need to set the host with db.useEmulator(), like in this [example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#android_ios_and_web_sdks)